# Bitbucket | Trigger Build on Pull request

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, pull-request

I have a Jenkins job which I want to trigger when I evaluate a pull request on Bitbucket. The Jenkins job is correctly configured (by the looks of it) with the 'Poll SCM' option checked.

I have setup the 'Bitbucket Server Webhook to Jenkins' as follows. When I click on 'Trigger Jenkins' as part of the configuration check, it works well. Corresponding logs on the Jenkins server show up properly.

[image]

Now, when I receive a pull request, I would want to trigger the same Jenkins job. However, which I click on the 'Trigger Build' option, **nothing happens**. The Jenkins job is **not triggered**. I **dont** see correspnding logs on the Jenkins server. No logs on the bitbucket server as well.

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

I am using an 'Atlassian Bitbucket  v4.7.1' evaluation installation and a Jenkins 1.651 installation.

Answer (score 2):

Just tried bitbucket 4.13 with webhook to jenkins for bitbucket 3.0.1 plugin. Follow the instruction on the plugin site, you need to install the git plugin on the jenkins side, enable git checkout and make sure it works, and enable polling of scm. The jenkins version used is pulled from docker hub with tag jenkins/jenkins:lts.

---

If the above does not work for you, from my reading you can have a few options as of today Nov 12 of 2017:

- Use the generic [post webhooks plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/nl.topicus.bitbucket.bitbucket-webhooks/server/overview) that supports pull request trigger. And from jenkins pick it up with the [generic webhooks plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin), then maybe do a secondary trigger from jenkins.
- Upgrade the bitbucket server and webhooks to jenkins plugin. The server 4.13 does not work well with later webhooks to jenkins plugin. A paid version of the plugin probably is your best choice.
- Or try bamboo that comes with the ["plan banches" feature](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/using-plan-branches-289276872.html).